# Получение Dll Base Address в памяти

Tags: delphi

Как узнать Dll Base Address в своём процессе? Приходится прибегать к вот таким извращениям:

```
uses
TLHelp32;

...

function GetModuleAddress(ModuleName : String; ProcessId : Cardinal): DWord;
var
 hSnap : THandle;
 md    : MODULEENTRY32;
begin
 Result := 0;
 hSnap := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, ProcessId);
 if ( hSnap < 1 ) Then Exit;
    if (Module32First(hSnap, md)) then
  begin
  if (ExtractFileName(md.szExePath) = ModuleName) then
  begin
   Result := DWord(md.modBaseAddr);
   CloseHandle(hSnap);
   Exit;
  end;
  while (Module32Next(hSnap, md)) Do
  begin
   if (ExtractFileName(md.szExePath) = ModuleName) then
   begin
    Result := DWord(md.modBaseAddr);
    Break;
   end;
  end;
 end;
 CloseHandle(hSnap);
end;

...

begin
 Edit1.Text := IntToHex(GetModuleAddress('dllname.dll', GetCurrentProcessId), 8);
end;
```

В таком случае получаем Адрес Dll в памяти, который можем проверить любым отладчиком/дебаггером.

Но по факту

```
var
 BaseAddr : Pointer;
begin
 BaseAddr := Pointer( DWord( LoadLibrary('dllname.dll') ) );
end;
```

Получается то же самое, что и выше.

Собственно, ещё раз сам вопрос. Как получить то же самое, но более просто?

Comment: Во-первых Dll Base Address != точка входа (Entry Point)

Comment: Ой, извините, точно. Что-то я забылся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `GetModuleHandle`
2. Пройтись по списку `PEB_LDR_DATA.InLoadOrderModuleList`, и вычислить свой модуль по имени или хешу, далее определить из полей структуры адрес загрузки.

[Пример](http://www.codereversing.com/blog/?p=94).